# AWS Config Rule for a Subset of S3 Buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, configuration

I have hundreds of S3 buckets.  I only have a handful of important buckets, which I always prefix with **important-**.

```bash
example-s3-bucket-1
example-s3-bucket-2
important-s3-bucket-1
example-s3-bucket-3
important-s3-bucket-2
...
```

I would like to run the AWS **s3-bucket-logging-enabled** Config Rule on **only** the buckets that begin with **important-** and ignore all other buckets.

```bash
# s3-bucket-logging-enabled Config Rule
Description:
Checks if logging is enabled for your S3 buckets. The rule is NON_COMPLIANT if logging is not enabled.

Enabled evaluation mode:
DETECTIVE 

Detective evaluation trigger type:
Oversized configuration changes
Configuration changes

Scope of changes:
Resources

Resource types:
S3 Bucket

Parameters:
targetBucket - Target S3 bucket for storing server access logs.
targetPrefix - Prefix of the S3 bucket for storing server access logs.
```

How do I do this?

Comment: you can add a tag to all your "important" buckets and use that tag in the config rule

Comment: Can I use a separate config rule to tag them?  Or do I use a Lambda function to tag them?

Comment: use a combination of AWS CLI and bash script.